# HyperLedger Fabric v1.4.4: Instantiating smart contract on mychannel with error

Tags: docker, npm, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am following the HyperLedger Fabric v1.4.4 "Writing Your First Application" tutorial[1], but I am having a problem running the code `./startFabric.sh javascript`:

```
+ echo 'Instantiating smart contract on mychannel'
Instantiating smart contract on mychannel
+ docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -l node -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P 'AND('\''Org1MSP.member'\'','\''Org2MSP.member'\'')' --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
2019-11-25 16:14:38.470 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-11-25 16:14:38.470 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/fabric-shim failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-11-25T16_17_00_000Z-debug.log
"
```

I think that error is related to the docker image, because it occurs when the following code is executed:

```
echo "Instantiating smart contract on mychannel"
docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${ORG1_MSPCONFIGPATH} \
  cli \
  peer chaincode instantiate \
    -o orderer.example.com:7050 \
    -C mychannel \
    -n fabcar \
    -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE" \
    -v 1.0 \
    -c '{"Args":[]}' \
    -P "AND('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')" \
    --tls \
    --cafile ${ORDERER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
    --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${ORG1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE}
```

I don't know much about docker, but I'm learning. Until then, does anyone help me with this problem?

[1] https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html

#### Update 1

The same error was observed when I run `./byfn.sh up -l node`, but no error for `./byfn.sh up`. I think the error is connected to fabric-shim. I am still looking for an answer to this error.

Comment: did you install all prerequisites? and did you generate artifacts before running the network?

Comment: Yes, many times, but it didn't help me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to Instantiate the smart contract will be trying to start a new chaincode container, and this is failing because the new container cannot successfully run `npm install` commands.

The problem could be a Docker DNS issue, or an npm registry connection problem due to the country or company you are connecting from.

The following 2 previous answers should help you:
[Network calls fail during image build on corporate network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network)

[Error while running fabcar sample in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000152/error-while-running-fabcar-sample-in-javascript)

Comment: It works for me! In one of the answers in [Network calls fail during image build on corporate network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network) there is a link to a Docker documentation that helped me: [Fix Docker's networking DNS config](https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/). Thanks.